# Performing modeling on multiple tsibbles in a tibble

Tags: r, time-series, tidyverse

I have a set of data that is in the form of the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(tsibble)
library(tsibbledata)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
library(fable)
library(fabletools)
library(tidymodels)
library(feasts)

data <- tibble(Date=yearweek(mdy("5/6/2022","5/14/2022","5/21/2022")),
           value=c(3,5,7))

ts_data <- tsibble(data)

new_test_data <- tibble(`Formula ID` = c(1),
                    `Formula Name` = c("Flubber"),
                    data=list(data),data_ts=list(ts_data))
```

This gives me tibble that looks like the following:

| Formula ID | Formula Name | data | data_ts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Flubber | 2 variables | 2 variables |

Where data is a tibble and data_ts is a tsibble.  I need to create a model for time series data_ts and forecast the time series.  I have been trying to use purrr to map the model as below:

```
new_test_data < new_test_data %>%
   mutate(model = map(data_ts,ARIMA(data_ts,value)))
```

This does not work, unfortunately.  Can someone offer me some pointers on getting this mapping to work to create a ARIMA model and the forecast from the model?  I have about 70 data sets within the new_test_data, making it perfect for this type of modelling.

Thank you kindly,

Shawn Way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps to get you started. To estimate an ARIMA or any other model you have to use `model()` which as its first argument takes a dataset and one or more model specifications, e.g. `ARIMA`. Moreover,  when using `map` to loop over a list column of datasets you have to pass a single element or dataset to `model()` not the list column itself.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(fabletools)
library(fable)
library(tsibble)

new_test_data <- new_test_data %>%
  mutate(model = map(data_ts, ~ model(.x, ARIMA(value))))

new_test_data$model |> map(report)
#> Series: value 
#> Model: ARIMA(1,0,0) w/ mean 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>       ar1  constant
#>         0    5.0000
#> s.e.    1    0.9428
#> 
#> sigma^2 estimated as 8:  log likelihood=-5.73
#> AIC=17.46   AICc=-6.54   BIC=14.75
#> [[1]]
#> # A mable: 1 x 1
#>           `ARIMA(value)`
#>                  <model>
#> 1 <ARIMA(1,0,0) w/ mean>
```

Comment: This let me understand the syntax perfectly!  Thank you very much!